# Smooth Streaming and AAC-Low Complexity audio codec. Data format?

Tags: audio, streaming, aac, expression-encoder, mpeg-4

I am writing a Smooth Streaming client application. On the server side (IIS 7 with Media Services extensions), I have a bunch of ISMV and ISMA files encoded using Expression Encoder pro 4 with the "H.264 IIS Smooth Streaming iPhone WiFi" preset. In a nutshell, it uses the "H.264 baseline" video codec, and the AAC-LC audio codec.

On the client side however is where I'm having problems, specifically with the audio chunks. While I have been able to make sense of the H.264 video stream (it is essentially a sequence of raw NAL units prefixed by their length, without the NAL unit "start code" 0, 0, 0, 1), I still haven't been able to crack what is inside the AAC LC audio stream, i.e. what comes in the "mdat" (Media Data Box) atom. It is most definitely *not* an MP4 container, but what is it then?

I am pasting below the first 128 (number chosen arbitrarily) bytes of one AAC-LC fragment (MDAT portion only) obtained from the server, in case anyone can figure it out from there.

```
unsigned char data[128] = {
 0x21, 0x09, 0x0A, 0xBF, 0xBF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0xB1, 0x8D, 0xC4, 0xA1,
 0x18, 0x0D, 0x25, 0xC9, 0x2E, 0x49, 0x2E, 0x10, 0x88, 0x91, 0x10, 0x01,
 0x13, 0x23, 0x2C, 0x36, 0x25, 0x60, 0x6B, 0x94, 0x8C, 0x74, 0xD7, 0x4A,
 0x95, 0xD3, 0x03, 0x91, 0x5B, 0x76, 0xDE, 0x27, 0xC5, 0xB2, 0x4C, 0xCF,
 0xEB, 0x3E, 0xDD, 0xFF, 0x22, 0xAF, 0xC3, 0xF8, 0x60, 0x36, 0x49, 0xBC,
 0xAE, 0x4D, 0x10, 0x31, 0xC6, 0x28, 0x2A, 0xEB, 0xCA, 0x94, 0x51, 0xD8,
 0x61, 0x1B, 0xC6, 0x2A, 0x91, 0x71, 0xE4, 0x8C, 0xF8, 0x19, 0x2C, 0xDE,
 0x71, 0xBB, 0xE3, 0xBD, 0x36, 0xB4, 0x45, 0x37, 0x02, 0x61, 0x48, 0x8E,
 0x19, 0x80, 0xD5, 0x24, 0x97, 0x24, 0x92, 0x44, 0x08, 0x89, 0x12, 0x00,
 0xB3, 0xF8, 0x1E, 0xE2, 0xBD, 0xCD, 0x4E, 0xF7, 0xA9, 0xE2, 0x0E, 0xD8,
 0xEA, 0xFA, 0xCF, 0xDB, 0x4E, 0x69, 0x6F, 0xEE
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long research and [this tip](http://forums.iis.net/p/1173507/1963529.aspx#1963529) I received on the IIS forums, I was able to figure it out. Basically this is a raw AAC stream, which needs to be wrapped with headers before it can be played back. The simplest and most common header format appears to be [ADTS](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=Understanding_AAC#Packaging.2FEncapsulation_And_Setup_Data), which consists in adding a [7-byte header in front of each sample](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/lofiversion/index.php/t21617.html).

Comment: So `.isma` file can be converted to regular audio file by adding such headers? Can you please recommend some tool or code that would convert `.isma` and `.ismv` files to file that can be played by some common player(s)?

Comment: You may want to create a separate question about this, as it's a rather complex topic. The answer in a nutshell however is that no, you can't just add the 7-byte header; you'd need to first parse out the ISO file metadata ('tfhd' box, 'trun' box, etc.) to figure out where the samples boundaries are. But if I recall correctly you can play (unencrypted) ISMA files with Windows Media Player?